# Agonal respiration

Tags: vocabulary

**Death Rattle**

> What is the sound called that an animal makes having been pounced on and dying? Like, when a lion holds the neck of a deer, such as. The sound that a prey makes while its throat is grasped.

Is this death rattle? I think this is used for humans, not sure though.

Truly speaking, I tried to find it, but I admit I failed.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/death%20rattle

Comment: https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=death%20rattle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, "death rattle" is something normally said in connection with humans. There's no specific reason you couldn't say it about an animal, except that it tends to describe the last breaths of persons dying 'naturally', perhaps of old age. It doesn't particularly refer to persons dying from respiratory problems or 'agonal breathing', which is someone gasping as they desperately try to catch a breath. It has just been observed that as people reach their final breaths they develop this 'rattle'.

If you're looking for a name for the sound made by an injured person or animal you might perhaps choose from *wheezing, gasping, panting, groaning, choking* or any synonyms of these.

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam-Webster *death rattle*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/death%20rattle)
: a rattling or gurgling sound produced by air passing through mucus in the lungs and air passages of a dying person

A death rattle is produced by mucus-restricted breathing, not by strangulation.

I don't think a deer with a lion at its neck is making any sound through it.